# javascript date creation, can't set the correct month

Tags: javascript

```
var d = new Date(2011,1,1);

alert(d);
```

this alert says February, while it should say January

anybody has some explanation for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScripts Date object zero-indexes months.

Try:

```
var d = new Date(2011,0,1);

alert(d);
```

Instead.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info!

Comment: Another reference: An [HTML version](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3.1) of the [actual specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Answer (score 6):

the month argument is zero based.  So 0 = jan, 1 = feb, etc....

Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp). Specifically at the part that says

> The setMonth() method sets the month (from 0 to 11), according to
>   local time.
>
> Note: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The month argument is 0 based so you should pass 0 for January.

```
var d = new Date(2011, 0, 1);
```