# Javascript and the Date() function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript date creation, can't set the correct month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913035/javascript-date-creation-cant-set-the-correct-month)

I have script like:

```
var year = 2011;
var month = 3;
var day = 1;

var start = new Date(year, month, day, 0,0,0,0);
```

When it comes time to use start I find that it ends up evaluating to April 4, 2011. Any ideas why the month gets bumped up by 1?

Comment: Recommend you read the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Jan starts at 0 in this notation.  So Apr is 3.

Comment: This "feature" wins the prize for most brain-dead API glitch ever. I mean, using 1 for January is *so* mainstream.

Comment: @Pekka In JavaScript, most countable properties start at zero. So, I find it very consistent, actually (day-of-the-week also start counting at zero).

Comment: @Rob till. When the mankind-wide convention for something is 1-12, making it 0-indexed is a *terrible* thing to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the only item in a date whose counter starts with a 1 is a date. Its the way  that has been defined.

Everything else (day, hour, min) the first item is defined with a 0.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Month starts at 0...?  Not sure I follow this.

Comment: if you consider months an array, month[0] = January

Answer (score 4):

The month starts counting at zero (see [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)).

So, January = 0, and December = 11.

Answer (score 2):

The month in JavaScript is based on a zero-based index.

```
January = 0;
February = 1;
...
```

Skimming the [`getMonth()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) on MDN will help explain this more fully.

Answer (score 1):

The months are zero-based. `0` corresponds to January, `3` to April.

Answer (score 1):

The months on the javascript Date object is 0 indexed.

```
0 = January
1 = February
2 = March
3 = April
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

month starts from 0 to 11.

0 - Jan, 1- Feb, and so on.