# date object not returning correct day value in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating date with numbers (new Date(2012, 03, …) gives wrong month (+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649036/creating-date-with-numbers-new-date2012-03-gives-wrong-month-1)

I have this function:

```
function myFunction(){
 var d = new Date(2012,9,1);
var x = document.getElementById("demo");//some element demo

x.innerHTML=d.getDay();

}
```

I am trying to get the weekday on 1 date of any month . The code is above(an example).
Isn't this supposed to return a saturday that is 6 as its value? It doesn't give correct value. It gives 1 in this case.It seems simple but i am missing something.
am i misinterpreting the equation ?

Please tell.

some edit: Although it is a little bit different but still it was on the same line.

```
 function myFunction()
{

for(i=0;i<12;i++){

  var d = new Date(2012,i,0);

  k=i+1;

  var x = document.getElementById(""+k);

   x.innerHTML=d.getDate()+" "+i;


  }

}
```

This function writes the particular ids 12 total in no. and i get the following output:

```
31 0

31 1

29 2

31 3

30 4

31 5

30 6

31 7

31 8

30 9

31 10

30 11
```

That is not correct.

The function above is generating out months and corresponding days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating date with numbers (new Date(2012, 03, ...) gives wrong month (+1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649036/creating-date-with-numbers-new-date2012-03-gives-wrong-month-1) and [javascript date creation, can't set the correct month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913035/javascript-date-creation-cant-set-the-correct-month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that when creating a new `Date` object, the `month` parameter takes a number between 0-11. September is 8. Try changing that to 8, and your day will return `6`, which is Saturday.

Your corrected code:

```
function myFunction(){
var d = new Date(2012,8,1);
var x = document.getElementById("demo");//some element demo

x.innerHTML=d.getDay();

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/T5FMH/)

Comment: damnit. Sometimes things get too messy to figure out even a simple problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ashishdabral Sure thing. Make sure you accept an answer to your question by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Comment: hi, one more thing: if i use                                              d= new Date(2012,8,0);                               limit=d.getDate(); shouldn't it return the no. of days in this month i.e 30. why does it return 31?

Comment: @ashishdabral Because July has 31 days?

Comment: but 8 is supposed to be september on a 0 to 11 scale as you said in your above post, isn't it ? where did july came into question?           My windows pc shows 30 days for september, i expect the output to be september.

Comment: @ashishdabral Oh, right. Sorry, brain malfunction. What `0` as a day does, is goes back a day. Which is the last day of the *previous* month. (1/08/2012 is 1st September. 0/08/2012 is 1 day behind 1st September, which is the 31st of August)

Comment: @ok, so it just returns no. of days in previous month.K. Thanks again.My code was working fine yesterday but with change of date it broke. Thanks , will fix it now.

Comment: date should only accept a rang of 1-31

Comment: @AshirvadSingh Browsers don't always follow the spec.

Comment: @AshirvadSingh: The page [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) says that not specifying values will pass 0 to the Date() funtion for unspecified parameters as argument. I think then we too can pass values if it accepts 0 as values.

Comment: @ashish go through thisd link ..it says valid date is from 1-31 and valid month is from 0-11 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @AshirvadSingh You are correct, but browsers change your date to make it as suitable as possible. If you put a date above 31, it goes to the next month. That's just the way it works.

Comment: @AshirvadSingh: I agree with you on that and that's why as Amaan pointed out it is not supposed to do anything with the specified month's date. It gives you the last day in previous month. I don't know why it does such a thing because there is no official thing i saw on this in use. but i have seen tutorial exploiting this. And it works for everyear even for leap year and seems like a good malfunctioning(if it really is and not a deliberate one).

Answer (score 1):

I got the culprit:

In Javascript month is treated as an array and starts from 0.

So for September it should be

```
var d = new Date(2012,8,1); and not 9
```

Answer (score 0):

i know that you can create dates by using the long timestamp.

sometime's it happens that you import the wrong date - you need Utils.Date and not SQL.Date - check for this, too!