# new Date() sets wrong month

Tags: javascript, date

I want to parse a string (or even the ints) at the **new Date()** function, but see what happens:

```
date = "2015-12-13"
"2015-12-13"
date
"2015-12-13"
date2 = new Date(date);
Sat Dec 12 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)
date2 = new Date(2015,12,13);
Wed Jan 13 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the code. Months start counting at zero, so December would be `11` and January `0`. Since you provided `12` as the month, it wraps around to the next month, which is January 2016.

Comment: JavaScript stores the value as a number but displays the result as a date. You need to use the Date functions to extract the information. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: The first result is because the date is being parsed in GMT, but displayed in your local timezone, which is 5 hours earlier.

Comment: Related: [javascript date creation, can't set the correct month](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6913035/710446), but it doesn't address the 12-to-0 modulo happening here.

Comment: **Never** parse strings using the *Date* constructor or *Date.parse*. `"2015-12-13"` may be treated as UTC, local or NaN by browsers in use. Even the standards writers have flip–flopped on how it should be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Month dates start at 0 in javascript, so **0** would be January and **11** would be December in your example.